# Python Pocketsphinx: Keyword not being recognised from a .wav file

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to detect the keyword `temperature` from a recording of me only saying the phase temperature (there are no other words present). Originally I used the keyword `hello` and it worked fine but whenever I try with any other word it does not. My current code is as follows:

```
import pocketsphinx as ps
import requests
import json
import sys, os

model_path = ps.get_model_path()
data_path = ps.get_data_path()

# Call to API
def get_temperature():
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': 'REMOVED'
    }

    response = requests.get(url=TEMPERATURE_URL, headers=headers)
    print("Response Code: ", response)

    temperature_data = response.json()
    print(temperature_data)
    temp = temperature_data[0]["value"]
    return temp

print("start")
while True:
    speech = ps.AudioFile(lm=False, kws='keyphrase.list', kws_threshold=1e-1)
    for phrase in speech:
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(phrase.segments(detailed=True))
        print(phrase)
        if phrase.__eq__('temperature '):
            print("if equal")
            temperature = get_temperature()
            print("Temperature: ", temperature)
```

The contents of my keyphrase.list file is:

```
temperature /1e-1/
```

It currently starts and runs but doesn't detect anything.

Edit: [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/clientaudio) is the audio file I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has wrong format:

```
file client_audio.wav 
client_audio.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, 4 channels 20000 Hz
```

You have to convert it to proper format 16 bit mono 16khz before decoding, it wouldn't work otherwise.

In case threshold is small, you can try different threshold values like 1e-10, 1e-20, 1e-30, 1e-40 to balance between detections and false alarms.

Comment: Hi there. Unfortunately I tried this and it didn't fix it. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Share an audio file you are trying

Comment: Edited the original to include this :)

Comment: Hi, I am now using a mono 16 bit 16kHz and have the kws_threshold set at 1e-40 and it still doesn't detect it, any other suggestions?

Comment: Update: For those of you still looking for an answer, use the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572429/python-pocketsphinx-keyword-isnt-recognised-when-using-decoder-class